# Cardinals as equivalence classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory

An excerpt from Wiki page on Cardinal numbers,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Formal_definition

"The oldest definition of the cardinality of a set X (implicit in Cantor and explicit in Frege and Principia Mathematica) is as the class [X] of all sets that are equinumerous with X. This does not work in ZFC or other related systems of axiomatic set theory because if X is non-empty, this collection is too large to be a set."

What exactly does not work? Wy should a cardinal be necessarily represented by a set? I think cardinal arithmetic works perfectly with this definition. Where do I have a problem if I define a cardinal as an equivalence class? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class of singletons is a proper class. So any cardinal larger than $0$ can be represented by a proper class of sets.

Why is it important? Well, for basic statements, like Cantor's theorem, it's not. You can do away with cardinals being proper classes. But being a foundational theory, it is more satisfying to know that something like a cardinality of a set can be internalized. That we can talk about cardinality of a set as part of our theory.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that for utilitarian purposes like infinite dimensional linear algebra introducing cardinals as equivalence classes causes no contradictions?

Comment: To some extent, yes. At least for very basic things, it's going to be doable. Your mileage may vary as far as how much the statements are more complicated. But if you already have ZFC and the cardinals, I don't see the point.

Comment: The point is not introducing too much terminology to a non-set-theorist who just wants to add and multiply dimensions of infinite dimensional vector spaces. This is like defining a manifold to be a locally regular embedding of a topological space into a higher dimensional Euclidean space. You can do that by Whitney's theorem, but it is not an internal definition. But still, if it helps a non-geometer to handle manifolds easier then it's justified, I think.

Comment: Sure, in naive terms, you can just always replace "cardinal" by the statement "whenever such and such set is in a bijection with this and that set, then we can do so on and so on either on both sets or on neither of them". So for example, "Given a nonzero Banach space $X$, then there is an injective function from the real numbers into $X$". The problem with that, is that when you talk like this, there is often an implicit context that the function is "in the right category", which isn't always the case.

Comment: An example of the above "in another category": If $X$ is a Hilbert space and there is a function from the natural numbers into $X$ whose range spans a dense subspace of $X$, then there is an injective function from $X$ into the real numbers. Wouldn't it be much much easier saying "If $X$ is a Hilbert space and there is a countable dense subset of $X$, then $|X|=2^{\aleph_0}$"?

Comment: The example is perhaps not too pertinent. Someone who deals with Hilbert spaces surely knows what a dense subset is: no additional terminology needs to be introduced. But when an analyst works with vector spaces he need not know at all what ordinals and cardinals are in their modern interpretations. Whereas equivalence classes of sets are as intuitive as one could wish. If one starts to refer to the state-of-the-art in the definition of every object one uses, papers will become encyclopedias.

Comment: I personally think if disjoint unions and cartesian products provide all the functionality you need in your paper, you don't need to introduce ordinals and cardinals in a proper way. But this may be a matter of taste.

Comment: I generally agree with you, that excessive terminology can---and often does---interrupt the natural statements of things. But then you have books like Halmos' "Naive set theory" which goes to great lengths to avoid talk about ordinals and cardinals properly, and it suffers greatly as a consequence (as do many people who study from that book, although often this suffering is unbeknownst to them). But to be fair, I don't recall many functional analysis papers involving ordinals and cardinals (except those specifically linked to set theoretic constructions).

Comment: I do nothing but agree. If you write about sets you'd better use proper set theory. Regarding functional analysis: yes, it is hard if not impossible to do without topology. And hence most analysts don't usually need ordinals and cardinals - vector spaces with tractable topology usually have tractable cardinalities. But harmonic analysis is a strange mix of algebra and analysis, and sometimes you do want to separate algebraic aspects from functional analytic ones. And there you meet cardinalities, but don't necessarily want to dwelve too much into them.